# Powershell OpenFileDialog to remain in front

Tags: .net, powershell, openfiledialog

I have powershell code that uses `OpenFileDialog` to get the user to select a file.

First time I execute the code the dialog box appears on top, but the second time, it appears behind the powershell GUI.

How to keep `OpenFileDialog` at the front?

```
<# courtesy of http://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-multi-line-input-box-dialog-open-file-dialog-folder-browser-dialog-input-box-and-message-box/ #>
function Read-OpenFileDialog([string]$WindowTitle, [string]$InitialDirectory, [string]$Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*",[switch]$AllowMultiSelect)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $openFileDialog.Title = $WindowTitle

    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($InitialDirectory)){
        $openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    }

    $openFileDialog.Filter = $Filter

    if ($AllowMultiSelect){
        $openFileDialog.Multiselect = $true
    }

    $openFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true

    $openFileDialog.ShowDialog() > $null

    if ($AllowMultiSelect){
        return $openFileDialog.FileNames
    }
    else{
        return $openFileDialog.FileName
    }

}


$filePath = Read-OpenFileDialog -WindowTitle "Select Executable" -InitialDirectory 'C:\' -Filter "Executable files (*.exe)|*.exe"

if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filePath)){
    Write-Host "You selected the file: $filePath"
}
else{
    "You did not select a file."
}
```

Comment: I get this behaviour running your script from the ISE, but if I save as a .ps1 and `Run with PowerShell` it opens in front everytime. Is this what you see?

Comment: @DeanOC yes if I save as .ps1 and     Run with PowerShell then it works, but right now I am debugging from ISE. How do I make this work so the dialog box is always in front of ISE?.